# Send HTML file via Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I got a HTML file (with CSS). I did that in Brackets. Now I want to send that as an email, so it looks the same. I tried to do it with "Add Attachment" and then "Insert as text", but it looks ugly and it seems like it doesn't apply the CSS. 
If you want to take a look at the code: http://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/woxByr
Everything is in the same file. (HTML & CSS)
I got one `<div id="wrapper>` that the email isnt full width. But when I import it to outlook with the method i mentioned above, it's just fullscreen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33954831/outlook-software-strips-out-the-inline-css-in-emails/33983305#33983305
The asnwer have some links that might be useful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete HTML support is not really wide-spread in mail clients... I had to learn that when I created my first newsletter.
Many clients don't fully support all the HTML5 tags and CSS (even if used inline).

I had the most consistent results when using tables to create the layout of the message. It's ugly to write but seems to get displayed correctly on the most used mail clients.

Check out the source code of some hmtl newsletters to get an idea about which html / css elements should work fine.

Some insights can also be found here:
https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-code-html-email-newsletters/

Answer (score 0):

As per above answer, you'll need to rebuild it in a more email friendly way.

But as for getting it into Outlook when you're done, one method I've used recently was to open the HTML file in Internet Explorer, select all > copy and then paste into a new Outlook message.

There might be some line breaks but you can remove those by selecting the line and just hitting delete.